# Как сделать, чтобы у Python не открывалась консоль?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Хочу сделать программу, но консоль очень сильно мешает. При этом у самой программы нет интерфейса. Можно ли как нибудь убрать консоль, чтобы не было никакого визуал запущенной программы, кроме, как процесса в диспетчере задач

Comment: Если windows, то поменять расширение скрипта с py на pyw